# Linux Ash Shell script to check if certain package is installed & called via docker

Tags: docker, shell, dockerfile, embedded-linux, ash

I'm trying to run docker on embedded Linux running OpenWRT.

Since the embedded Linux is a "resource constraint" I don't want Docker to install already installed packages, therefore I want to call a custom shell script with docker:

```
RUN $CMD_STRING = $(gcc)
RUN $CMD_OUTPUT=$(${CMD_STRING} -version) 

RUN if [[ ${CMD_OUTPUT} == *"not found"* ]]; echo ${CMD_STRING} "was NOT FOUND, Installing..." 
    opkg update
    opkg install gcc
fi
```

I will like a similar simple if/else structure.

**I keep getting:**

```
-ash: gcc: not found
-ash: -rw-r--r--: not found
```

Comment: The Docker container will be fully isolated from the host system; it can't use anything installed on the host, including the host's package manager.  Container images are frequently based on a mainstream Linux distribution (Debian, Ubuntu, or Alpine) and you need to use the image's distribution's package manager (`apt-get` or `apk`), regardless of what the host system is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have some OpenWRT for test but this may work if its only an "ash" and "docker" problem. I tested it on alpine since it also have ash (from busybox).

Dockerfile:

```
from alpine:latest

RUN ash -c "if ! gcc 2>/dev/null; then echo 'not found..'; echo 'installing..'; fi"
```

Build it:

```sh
docker build . 
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/2 : from alpine:latest
 ---> 389fef711851
Step 2/2 : RUN ash -c "if ! gcc 2>/dev/null; then echo 'not found..'; echo 'installing..'; fi"
 ---> Running in 2c47bee97dfc
not found...
installing.. 
Removing intermediate container 2c47bee97dfc
 ---> 35e698d1aea6
Successfully built 35e698d1aea6
```

Answer (score 0):

You have extra spaces in your first command, and shouldn't be using a variable name with a dollar sign at the beginning. I think you probably also don't want to be assigning that with `$()`, since you haven't tested if it exists yet. Trying to run a command to see if it exists also isn't a great way to go about it. You can see if a program is installed like this:

```
if ! command -v gcc &> /dev/null; then
  opkg install gcc
fi
```

(That's POSIX-compatible so should work in ash.)

You could also run `opkg list-installed` and check the output (see [the docs](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/additional-software/opkg#informational_commands)) which may be useful for packages that aren't executables in your PATH.